# How to restore desktop color settings?

Tags: xorg, colors, desktop

OS is Debian 12. Video driver is Nvidia 525.147.05.

I'm trying to play an older game via wine that uses directx. (diablo 2). I launched the game in windowed mode, but when I did so, the colors of the *entire screen* changed. (brightness, contrast, gamma as far as I can tell). The game runs fine, but when quitting the game, the previous color settings are unfortunately not restored.

What is going on here? How can an application change the color settings for the entire desktop? How would I determine what settings exactly were changed? I don't see any sort of settings for brightness or contrast etc in `nvidia-settings`.

How would I try and restore the color settings to how they looked before I launched the game? Is there any way to "lock" these color settings so that random applications can't change them? I could understand a single application changing the settings for its *own* colors, but interfering with the entire desktop is quite bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

What actually happened was probably Wine switching the display color depth from the usual 32/24-bit "true-color" mode (= millions of colors available simultaneously) to e.g. 16-bit indexed color mode because of DirectX, and failing to switch it back properly.

In an indexed color mode, the entire screen has a set of color registers, whose values can be chosen out of the full millions-of-colors range, but you can only have as many different colors on the screen at the time as there are color registers available (e.g. 65536 colors in 16-bit indexed color mode, or even just 256 colors in 8-bit mode). In X11 terminology, these indexed color modes were known as PseudoColor modes.

Back when X11 was originally developed, true-color displays were not a common thing, and such adaptation was necessary to support the ability to have multiple programs (optionally created by multiple systems over the network) all display in windows of the same screen.

Here is a description of the requirements for X11 applications that came from dealing with this kind of adaptability: [https://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/X11visuals.html](https://hea-www.harvard.edu/%7Efine/Tech/X11visuals.html)

Their description of the different color modes and their effect on the user is particularly appropriate:

> The 24-bit Truecolor visual is basically unlimited colors. You want a color, you get that color. You don't have to allocate colors, you don't ever run out of colors, and you don't have to settle for a color that is not exactly what you want.
>
> 8-bit PseudoColor will mean that the application is limited to 256 colors. Moreover, these colors are generally shared across all applications. So if some other application is using 245 shades of brown, your application gets black and white (pretty much always allocated, plus those browns, plus up to 9 other colors of your choosing. Unless there's more than that one other application running, in which case the colormap is probably full, and you can't choose any colors.
>
> Of course, 8-bit applications can run with a "private colormap". That means that the application can use any 256 colors of it's own choosing, without competing with other applications. The downside to this is that on most hardware, this results in "colormap flashing". As you move from one application to the next, the entire screen switches to a different colormap, which causes all of the non-current applications to look like psychadelic puke. Some users are willing to live with private colormaps to get adequate colors. Most users however, can not stand it.

Windows did much the same, but they had enforced a set of 16 or so "default colors" which were supposed to be included in the color indexes of all programs if at all possible, and the window decorations and other UI elements were designed to use only those colors whenever possible, minimizing the color distortions when switching between programs.

The good news is that the actual color settings of your desktop *have not* in fact changed: you are just viewing your usual desktop using a restricted set of colors. Anything that would reset the X server (like logging out & back in) should restore the normal state.

Unfortunately, since true-color displays have since then became the norm, dealing with the effects of PseudoColor modes and even switching from one color mode to another has become a bit of a lost art. Modern desktops expect the display to run at its full native resolution and color depth all the time. But your use of an old DirectX game has thrown a wrench into the works.

It used to be possible to switch between different display modes configured in the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad+</kbd> and -<kbd>Numpad-</kbd> keys, but these days, the display modes are auto-detected and the mode-switching keystrokes may be disabled by default, because an average modern user would be very confused if they hit either of thous keystrokes accidentally.

I think any program or tool that would be capable of telling X11 to switch the display color mode would have to use the `libXtst` library, but I could not find one that could be effectively used to reset the display back to the default true-color mode. You might try the `xrefresh` command, but I don't hold out much hope: I think it doesn't quite do what is needed here.